# How can I figure out which apps have access to my Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I authorized a few apps to work with Gmail. I want to figure out which ones and revoke permission. Do you know where I can find the list of those apps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's probably the "Authorized Access" section in your Google Account. Go to [Google Account](https://www.google.com/accounts/) and click "Change Authorized Websites". (For me the URL is https://www.google.com/accounts/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens )