# How can I determine which websites I have created accounts on using authentication methods?

Tags: facebook, google-account

I have used my Facebook account and Gmail account to access dozens of sites.

How can I find out on which sites I've used these authentication methods?

Comment: Are you referring to Facebook or Gmail? Because there’s Gmail in the title and Facebook in the body of the question.

Comment: Your Gmail question is a duplicate of this one: [How can I figure out which apps have access to my Gmail?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5929/354)

Comment: So you should probably change this question to be just about Facebook (which may also have a duplicate).

Comment: @AlE. Thanks for the tag wiki edit, that was a goof on my part.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking two similar questions. My answer will try and address both.

To see which sites have used Google Authentication:

1. Login to your Google/Gmail account.
2. Visit their [account permissions page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1)

To see which sites have used the Facebook Authentication:

1. Login to your Facebook account.
2. Visit their [app settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)

More info: Facebook uses a variant of the OAuth2.0 protocol. Google+ Sign-In is built on the OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect protocols.