# What can cause a message to be moved to Trash in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, inbox-by-gmail

I regularly receive promotional emails from Pizza Hut in Israel. I only ever notice them, though, because they cause my phone to buzz and if I look quickly enough I see the message. Within seconds, though, the message is always moved to my "Trash" folder. I don't have any custom filters that send messages to trash (in the "Filters and Blocked Addresses" tab of the settings menu), so I don't think that could be it.

I initially suspected that the all-Hebrew messages were causing the spam filter to filter those messages out, but again, they're in "Trash" not "Spam".

The beginning of this happening may have corresponded with my switching to Google Inbox from classic Gmail, but I'm not sure about this. What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: I think there is no automated delete process except filter settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail will only move messages to Trash automatically if you have a filter set up. (Blocked addresses go to Spam.)

More than likely you have given access to your Gmail account to some third-party application. (There are any number of apps which profess to help you organize your email.) Check that you haven't forgotten about one of them. (See: [How can I figure out which apps have access to my Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5929/354))

Comment: That was it! I had a third-party app for managing my inbox deleting Israeli Pizza Hut ads.